# unexpected SQLAlchemy object state after session.delete

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Say we have a SQLAlchemy ORM class User and a User object:

```
ed_user = User(name='ed', nickname='eddie')
```

We can find the object's state

```
state_of_ed_user = sqlalchemy.inspect(ed_user)
```

The state starts from transient as expected

```
assert state_of_ed_user.transient == True
```

Then becomes persistent after session.commit()

```
session.commit()
assert state_of_ed_user.persistent == True
```

However, after session.delete(), I expected the state of the object would be updated to deleted (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState.deleted), however, it's not updated.

```
session.delete(ed_user)
assert state_of_ed_user.deleted == False
assert state_of_ed_user.persistent == True
```

Have I understood session.delete incorrectly?
I am on SQLAlchemy 1.3.23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Quickie Intro to Object States](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_state_management.html) for more background of the session states.

Here it’s stated that an object gets the `deleted` state when it’s deleted within a flush.

Run `session.flush()` (normally part of `session.commit()`) to see the `deleted` state of the object.